# How to display values in the autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the code that i am using to display the values

```
function showHint(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str.length == 0) { 
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
        }
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.border="1px solid #ddd";



}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "search.php?q="+str+"&choice="+concept, true); 
xhttp.send();   
}
```

Which is currently being displayed in a div, I want it to be displayed in the autocomplete function below

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" autocomplete="off">
<div id= "txtHint">
<div id= "result">
```

How can I do that?
Note: The code is OK and it is displaying the values in the div 'result' successfully

Comment: Please provide a sample set of results

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI library has this feature:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Here is another Ajax Option:

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

And there is this one:

http://easyautocomplete.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for autocomplete with remote / API data. by using [JQuery UI](http:////code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js%22) with Its [CSS](http:////code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)

```
  $('.autosuggest').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: api + "GetAutoCompleteSuburb?SuburbName=" +   $('[id$=txtSuburb]').val(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    minChars: 0,
                   cacheLength: 1,
                   max:0,
                      cache: false,
                    delay: 0,
                    success: function (data) {

                        var a = data;
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('☺')[0],
                                val: item.split('☺')[1]
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            open: function (e) {
                valid = false;

            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                valid = true;
                $('[id$=txtSuburb]').val(ui.item.label);
                $('[id$=txtSuburbId]').val(ui.item.val);


            },
            close: function (e) {
                if (!valid) $(this).val('');

            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {
                    $('[id$=txtSuburb]').val("");
                    $('[id$=txtSuburbId]').val("0");

                }

            }
        });
    });
```

for Live editing please check with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/)

Comment: I tried doing it your way but failed. Can you look at my code above and tell me what changes do I have to make in my code? The suggestions are coming from a php file and not in Jason format either.